# Convert Array to JSON file

Tags: xcode, arrays, json

I use JSONKit to convert data inside my .json file to NSMutableArray.
How can i convert Array back to JSON data and write it to file?
May be use some other Kits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SBJsonWriter` class for this:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter new];
NSString *jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:yourArray];
```

You can find some help from
[Converting NSArray -> JSON -> NSData -> PHP server ->JSON representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290767/converting-nsarray-json-nsdata-php-server-json-representation)

[SBJsonWriter Nested NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765037/sbjsonwriter-nested-nsdictionary/12383548#12383548)

Comment: what if i want to make "arrayWithObject"? And how can I then write it to existings file here:     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"try" ofType:@"json"];