# how to send an array as a parameter to json service in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsmutablearray

I am using iPhone JSON Web Service based app.I need to pass input parameter as an array to a JSON web Service, how can I do this?

Array Contains 12 elements.
Here am providing sample service...
input parametes for this service:
dev_id = 1;
dev_name= josh and array items (projectslist,companyidentifier)

http://www.jyoshna.com/api/developer.php?dev_id=1&dev_name=josh&(Here i need to pass the array elements)

**can any help us how to pass array as a input parameter to the json service?**

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290767/converting-nsarray-json-nsdata-php-server-json-representation

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert array as JSON string

```
NSString *requestString=[jsonParser stringWithObject:array];
```

convert string to data

```
NSData *data=[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

set that data as request Body

```
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **serialize** the array and pass as an argument. Dont forget to **unserialize** in server side

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create an NSMutabelDictionary of your array then JSON encode it, you can then send the resulting string you your webservice however you choose. I tend to build a POST request and send it that way

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *tagData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%i", i];
    [tagData setObject:[array objectAtIndex:i] forKey:keyString];
}

[jsonDict setObject:tagData forKey:@"entries"];

NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString* aStr;
aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It is the sgtring aStr that you need to send