# iPhone how to post nsarry with json

Tags: ios, iphone, json, post, ios5

I have many json objects like:

```
{"id":"1","list":"456","name":"a"}, {"id":"2","list":"456","name":"b"}, {"id":"3","list":"456","name":"c"}
```

they stored in `NSDictionary` dic1, dic2, dic3, then I use `NSArray` store these dics,

Here is my question, How can I post these dictionaries?

I know post one json object, Here is my code

```
NSString *url = [SERVERPREFIX stringByAppendingString:urlString];
DLog(@"url:%@", url);
NSURL *reqURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData ***__jsonData**;
// Be sure to properly escape your url string.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:reqURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: **__jsonData**];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (unsigned int)[__jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
```

}

So, the question is what the **__jsonData** should be?

Comment: Please look into below answer. This is very much similar to what you want.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290767/converting-nsarray-json-nsdata-php-server-json-representation

Comment: i have a solution using xml tag structure but i'm unable to show it in answer so please use this way     Try this formate
   
   <userDetails> 
   <details>
   <id>1</id>
   <list>as</list>
   <name>charan</name>
   </details>
   <details>
   <id>2</id>
   <list>as</list>
   <name>charan</name>
   </details>
  </userDetails>

   here run a loop for <details>
   <id>2</id>
   <list>as</list>
   <name>charan</name>
   </details> and assign variables to id,name and list so will be have a xml structure here with list of information

Answer (score 2):

The `jsonData` should be:

```
jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourNSArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
convert your array to json

```
NSString *sendingData = [yourarray JSONRepresentation];
```