# Send array to PHP from objective C using POST/GET

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, arrays, json

I am trying to send an array of strings from Objective C to PHP. I was using GET initially but I got to know that GET is not suitable for sending large amount of data. My array would have approximately 300 entries. Therefore, I am using POST. [After going through this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290767/converting-nsarray-json-nsdata-php-server-json-representation?lq=1)  I came up with the following code

```
 NSDictionary *userconnections = [user objectForKey:@"connections"];
             NSMutableArray *connectionsID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (id foo in [userconnections objectForKey:@"values"]) {

                 [connectionsID addObject:[foo objectForKey:@"id"]];
                 //[User sharedUser].connections = connectionsID;

             }

             NSError *error;
             NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:connectionsID options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

             NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             [User sharedUser].connections = jsonData;
             [User sharedUser].connectionsID = jsonString;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/API.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:[[User sharedUser]connectionsID] forKey:@"songs"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[[User sharedUser] connections] length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody: [[User sharedUser] connections]];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Return DATA contains: %@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]);
```

In my PHP, I receive it like:

```
    <?php 

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$headers = array_change_key_case(getallheaders());


include "dbconnect.php";

$songs = json_decode(stripcslashes($_GET["songs"]));
echo json_encode($songs);
```

However, I am not able to receive data in php. Any help or pointers would be appreciated

**EDIT:** I switched back to using GET since POST was not helping me. Thank you for any help you may offer

Comment: if you look at just the body is it form encoded? I think it needs to be to show up in $_POST... otherwise I think you have to get it out of the raw request.

Comment: also you should look at the request through Charles proxy.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues:

1. You are building a `Content-Type` of `application/json` request, but your PHP is trying to read the `$_POST['songs']`. You should do one or the other (either send raw JSON request, or send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request). Let's assume you just wanted to create simple JSON request (as your Objective-C code is largely doing now). In that case, your PHP should read the raw JSON like so:

   ```
   <?php

   // be a good citizen and report that we're going to return JSON response

   header("Content-Type: application/json");

   // get the lower case rendition of the headers of the request

   $headers = array_change_key_case(getallheaders());

   // extract the content-type

   if (isset($headers["content-type"]))
       $content_type = $headers["content-type"];
   else
       $content_type = "";

   // if JSON, read and parse it

   if ($content_type == "application/json")
   {
       // read it

       $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
       $raw_post_data = '';
       while (!feof($handle)) {
           $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
       }
       fclose($handle);

       // parse it

       $songs = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
   }
   else
   {
       // report non-JSON request and exit
   }

   // now use that `$songs` variable here

   // if you wanted to report it back to the client for debugging purposes, you should
   // recreate JSON response:

   $raw_result = json_encode($songs);

   // finally, write the body of the response

   echo $raw_result;

   ?>
   ```
2. I would suggest removing the the `setValue:forKey:` with the `@"songs"` key in your Objective-C code. Assuming you just wanted to send the raw JSON request like I outlined above, then this is not needed (and, frankly, is the wrong way to send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, anyway).

If you intended to make the payload so that you could use `$_POST['songs']`, then the Objective-C code to do that does not use `setValue:forKey:`, but consists of manually building a request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and the `songs=...` would be in the body of the request (and you'd have to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to encode the JSON string you'd pass in this request). This is all a bit academic, though, as I think you should stick with the `application/json` request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I did have the json header in my php. I have updated my php code that should give you a better idea of what my file looks like.

Comment: @ShrutiKapoor That's great. But lack or presence of the JSON header is not the problem. It's that your Objective-C code is creating a JSON request (not a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request), but your PHP was using `$_POST`, which is intended only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and similarly encoded requests. Since you're just sending raw JSON in the request body, you should therefore change the PHP to read the raw data of the request body, which it can then convert with `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the widely used AFNetworking library (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). A simple POST request with parameters can be constructed like this:

```
NSDictionary *p = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:p success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking 2.0 has AFHTTPSessionManager class with POST method

```
(NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id<AFMultipartFormData>))block success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))failure;
```

pass connectionsID into parameters

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"connectionsID": [connectionsID copy]};
```

which can be accessed in PHP

```
$_POST['connectionsID']
```