# Proper JSON encoding for HTTP POST request in iOS

Tags: ios, json

Posted a query previously about JSON parsing not working properly. Did more looking into it with a packet sniffer and also with another client that works properly and found out it's a syntax thing, that I still can't seem to solve.

The code in the bottom makes the HTTP request to have the JSON in it as: 
{"key":"value"}

And my server is actually looking for a JSON in the following syntax: 
key=%22value%22

I tried to write some code that does this manually, but figured there must be something out of the box for iOS, and I don't want to have faults in the future.

I messed around with it for a while trying to find the right code for the job, but couldn't (you can see some code I tried commented out). Can anyone help me?

```
+ (NSString*)makePostCall:(NSString*)urlSuffix
                       keys:(NSArray*)keys
                    objects:(NSArray*)objects{
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    // NSString *dataString = [self getDataStringFromDictionary:params];
    // NSData *jsonData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];

    // id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    // NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);

    if (!jsonData) {
        // should not happen
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"Got an error parsing the parameters: %@", error);

        return nil;
    } else {
        // NSString *jsonRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // NSLog(@"%@", jsonRequest);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlPrefix, urlSuffix]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];


        // NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        // [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

        NSURLResponse * response = nil;
        NSError * error = nil;

        NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];

        // TODO: handle error somehow

        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: You said, "my server is actually looking for a JSON in the following syntax: key=%22value%22". That's not JSON. Are you sure your server requires JSON?

Comment: It's not? so what kind of format is that? (forgive my ignorance :-) ) 

More importantly - do you know how I can get to it from the JSON that I have?

Comment: %22 is the hex code for a quotation mark. As Rob said, that's not valid JSON. Are you sure they really want a %22 and not quotes? If so, you might be able to convert the JSON data to an NSString, call [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22"] and then call [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] on the result and pass that as the body. But if they only want %22s on the right-hand side of each item, you would probably be better off formatting the JSON by hand using an NSMutableString. Or get better server engineers.

Comment: Replacing " with %22 might not be perfect since the syntax of JSON is not exactly like key=%22value%22, there's : instead of =. I can't seem to find a set of commands to make the Dictionary into URL params

Comment: @LiorZ Your Objective-C code for generating the requests looks ok (though I'd discourage you from doing synchronous requests). I think you should turn your attention to your server code, as your description of what it's looking for sounds highly suspicious. If using PHP, perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548399/send-array-to-php-from-objective-c-using-post-get or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910578/objective-c-json-php-array. If you're still having problems, share your server code with us and we can take a look at that.

Comment: I checked again; what happens is that the *content* of each parameter the server expects is actually JSON, but each parameter is sent separately. 
Trying to convert the NSDictionary to a bunch of NSString* representing JSONs isn't easy either, as it seems.