# NSArray issue in iOS

Tags: php, ios, nsarray

I am sending array object To php server. I'm not sure how to send array format data to php server

when i'm trying to send array format my array format look like.How to remove brases and double quotes

```
"(

vdsvvdsvdsv

)"
```

Please let me know how can I do it properly.

Comment: Please use the post method to send the array

Comment: Your array is probably an Optional. Is it?

Comment: hi Thaks for reply,i am using post Methode but Its Not taken in backend i am sneding like this [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&projectSponsor=%@&projectid=%@", userId,addSponsorEmailStringInModel,projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Please add code to your question and format it, don't add in the comments. And what is the array in that code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `NSArray` to `NSData` and then to a JSON string before sending it to the server.

Hope this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323594/3336675

**EDIT:**

```
NSMutableString *jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"{\"userId\":\""];
[jsonString appendFormat:@"%@\",\"projectSponsor\":\"%@\",\"projectId\":\"%@\"}", userId, addSponsorEmailStringInModel, projectId];
```

Then

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://url.com/..."];

NSMutableData *responseData;

NSString* escapedUrlString =[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL* serverUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:serverUrl];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; //set value according to your requirement
```

Then

```
[request setHTTPBody:[NSString stringWithString:jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

And then if you want the return value, use this

```
NSURLResponse *res = nil;
NSError *err = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&res error:&err];//or asynchronous, as you wish
```

`data` now holds the returned JSON object

Comment: I am sending like this this correct way or not                                                  [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&projectSponsor=%@&projectid=%@", userId,addSponsorEmailStringInModel,projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way. Just make sure that the string in the request body is in a proper JSON format

Comment: but,backend store like this "(

vdsvvdsvdsv

)" i need to stroe like---- string1,string2

Comment: Post the API you are trying to call or else it is really confusing

Comment: I am talking about the API, I mean the full URL you are trying to call via your app. And also the HTTP request body format.

E.g: 
URL- http://something.com/something?
Request Body- {"userID":"123456789","projectId":"myproject"}

Comment: error NSMutableURLRequest declears the selector setHTTPBody
 dataUsingEncoding:

Comment: can u tell me how to get string data in array like ["test1@test.com","test2@test.com","test3@test.com"]

Comment: Use `[arrayName addObject:string];`. But I don't think the problem lies there

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&projectSponsor=%@&projectid=%@", userId,addSponsorEmailStringInModel,projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Should actually be 2 parts

```
NSString *emails = [addSponsorEmailStringInModel componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&projectSponsor=%@&projectid=%@", userId,emails,projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

So that you are explicitly converting your array into the string format expected by the server

Comment: i got tz error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString componentsJoinedByString:]: unrecognized selector

Comment: So when are you creating `addSponsorEmailStringInModel` and how?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server's code which is written to handle input streams.

Basically server transfer needs either XML or JSON data.

For JSON pick a simple parser like [SBJSONParser](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) and pass the array to it. (With sbjson we can even convert)

For XML you would need to use NSDATA to convert data to bytes and then pass it into  tag.